# Need help on Android apps: text_animation.xml errors

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm doing a book example that creates an animation app. This is the code for `text_animation.xml` that has problem (in `/res/anim`-folder):

```
<rotate android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="-45"
    android:toYScale="0.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="700"
    android duration="400"
/>
```

But the error message is:

> Attribute name "android" associated with an element type "rotate" must
>   be followed by the ' = ' character.

What is happening, and I know  tag is correct.  How to overcome this error message?  Thank you for any help.

Comment: `android duration="400"` you're missing the `:`, or is this just a typo?

Comment: Sorry, I discover that I forgot the ":" in the last statement.  It should be "android:duration="400" not "android duration="400"

Comment: It was just a simple mistake.  I fixed it, and it worked fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you post full xml ?
This is from documentation - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@[package:]anim/interpolator_resource"
    android:shareInterpolator=["true" | "false"] >
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="float"
        android:toAlpha="float" />
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="float"
        android:toXScale="float"
        android:fromYScale="float"
        android:toYScale="float"
        android:pivotX="float"
        android:pivotY="float" />
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="float"
        android:toXDelta="float"
        android:fromYDelta="float"
        android:toYDelta="float" />
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="float"
        android:toDegrees="float"
        android:pivotX="float"
        android:pivotY="float" />
    <set>
        ...
    </set>
</set>
```